# “The handle is invalid.” error in Windows 7 Enterprise

Tags: windows-7, windows

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask. I downloaded Open Office 3.3.0 to install. When I ran the installer, I got the following error.

```
[Window Title]
C:\Users\ashvets\Desktop\OOo_3.3.0_Win_x86_install-wJRE_en-US.exe

[Content]
C:\Users\ashvets\Desktop\OOo_3.3.0_Win_x86_install-wJRE_en-US.exe

The handle is invalid.


[OK]
```

I googled this error and got a bunch of responses that gave me the impression that this is a Windows problem at some depth in the OS and not with the installer. Anyone have this before? How did you get around resolving this problem?

I tried saving this file in another folder and installing it, no such luck.

Comment: Have you tried downloading again? It is possible that the file got corrupted during the download.

Comment: Yes and that did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Have you tried scanning for viruses?

Comment: Doing that now.  But here's the thing, I can double-click on other executables and those run.

Comment: Yeah, pretty sure that it's not a virus issue.  Anyone have _anything_ similar to this ever before?

Comment: The issue was with McAffee Solidifier installed on our machines.  It was stealthily installed and we could do nothing about it.

We got rid of it now.